# Does JPA allow to create the same table structures but different name of tables?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a simple JPA (Spring data Jpa) use case for simple forums.

This project is done by Spring MVC, Spring Data Jpa with hibernate as a jpa vendor and it consists of forum/forum_comment pojo entity, forum/forum_comment repository, and forum controller (restful)

jpa creates just 2 tables - forum and forum_comments

some time later,  I have new requests to generate new forums called forum2 which will be forum2 and forum2_comments and later more forums with different names I need to define

all of columns on forums and forum_comments are the same; but just different name of entity/table

Is there any smart way to generate different table names with same columns?

now I just do with manual copy and paste and rename these.

forum/forum_comment
forum2/forum2_comment
forum3/forum3_comment

like this stupid way; any guide will be helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Designated annotation for inheriting mappings without building entity hierarchy
is [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html).

Other way to solve problem is to not create new table for each forum, but storing all data in existing tables. New column can then be added to differentiate between forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Embeddable for the columns in each table.

See: http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/01/hibernate-embeddable-objects/

Comment: I expect something from Admin UI page such as "Type your table name" then it creates the tables dynamically; anyway this is better way. Thank you a lot for the answer :)